# Getting OOM error while fetching 200,000 records from Oracle DB in Java

Tags: java, jdbc, out-of-memory, heap-memory

My java app fetches about 200,000 records in its result set.

While trying to fetch the data from Oracle DB, the server throws **java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space**

One way to solve this, IMO, is to fetch the records from the DB in smaller chunks (say 100,000 records in each fetch or even smaller count). How can I do this (meaning what API method to use)?

Kindly suggest how to do this or if you think there's a better way to overcome this memory space problem, do suggest. I do not want to use JVM params like -Xmx because I read that that's not a good way to handle OutOfMemory errors.

Comment: setFetchSize method should help.  A smarter WHERE clause and processing strategy might be good, too.  Where'd you read that?  It's only bad if you don't understand root cause and postpone the inevitable.

Comment: What is a "lakh record"?

Comment: lakh means 100,000. For the benefit of the non-Indian readers here though it should probably be written "100,000" :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Oracle DB you may set `AND ROWNUM < XXX` to your SQL query. This will cause that only XXX-1 rows will be fetched in query.

Other way is to call `statement.setFetchSize(xxx)` method before executing statement.

Setting larger JVM memory pool is poor idea, because in future there may be larger data set which will cause OOM.